# Adding Selenium in IntelliJ creates NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: intellij-idea, selenium-webdriver

I am getting NoClassDefFoundError in IntelliJ but I think I have set the source folder correctly. The code works if I remove references of Selenium (version 3.5.3).

This works

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
public class NavigateToAUrl {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("test2");
//        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    }
}
```

but this doesn't

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
public class NavigateToAUrl {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("test2");
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    }
}
```

Comment: Most likely, your project is missing some required dependencies, refer to https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-module-dependencies.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had downloaded incompatible libraries. I needed Selenium 2.33.0 jar and the firefox version should have been 17.0.1.